# How to write a command to history in fish shell?

Tags: command-history, fish

In the `zsh` shell, I can write something into the command line history like so:

```
#!/bin/zsh
cmd="cd /special/dir" 
print -s $cmd"        # save command in history for reuse
```

How may I do that in the `fish` shell?

Comment: There's `print -s` in ksh93 and zsh, but though `bash` has a `print` example loadable builtin (often not installed let alone enabled by default), it just ignores the `-s` option.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, i have edited this question. But do you have a way to save command to history in a fish script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT, only the `read` builtin and the shell command line reader can add entry to the history, but only when stdin is a tty device, so that's not easily scriptable.

But you could add the entry by hand with something like:

```
function add_history_entry
  begin
    flock 1
    and echo -- '- cmd:' (
      string replace -- \n \\n (string join ' ' $argv) | string replace \\ \\\\
    )
    and date +'  when: %s'
  end >> $__fish_user_data_dir/fish_history
  and history merge
end
```

And then:

```
add_history_entry 'cd /special/dir'
```

That works for me with fish 3.1.2 here, but note that `fish` is a bit of a moving target with API changing often in incompatible ways between one version and the next. That `__fish_user_data_dir` and the format of the history file are not documented, so they might go away/change in a future version. The above also assumes the `$fish_history` variable is not set to anything other than `fish`.